# How can I idiomatically access the first element of a single element hash in Perl?

Tags: perl, hash

I have script that gets some data using DBI's fetchall_hashref().

Usually it returns a hash ref like the following:

```
{ 1 => { id => 1 } }
```

However, I'm only interested in the value of the first item in the hash, which is the max value of a particular column. I know Perl hashes are not ordered, but luckily this particular query always return exactly 1 or 0 records (since this is a MAX() query).

But the code currently used to achieved that is really ugly:

```
$results->{(keys %{$results})[0]}->{'id'};
```

Is there a more elegant way to active this? (Without resorting to CPAN modules)

**Clarification**

I'm getting the hash from a data access layer that we use in house. Everything gets returned via fetchall_hashref(). I don't call the fetchall_hashref() itself, it's just how the data access functions are implemented internally, so I'm told. I'm a consumer of that returned data and it happens to be in the form of a hash. I'm looking for a more concise way, if it exists, to access the results of single return value queries

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can dereference the `id` key of the first value in `%$results`:

```
(values %$results)[0]->{id};
```

Normally, this would not be [well defined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-defined) since [the ordering of values returned `keys` or `values` can be different even between runs on the same machine using the same `perl`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html), but since you said `%$results` can only ever contain one or zero elements, this is a valid method.

Comment: Can be extended to get the second first value as well: `(values %{(values %$results)[0]})[0]`

Comment: `(values %$results)[0]->{id};` is perfect. It expresses clearly that you are not interested in the entire `%$results`, only its values. No need to try to add more *value* to it.

Comment: @fork0 you use `values` for this task and have taken a 2nd place :D but in readability this is 1st.

Comment: I tried (values %$results)[0]{id}; Seems to work. Shaves off two characters.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of fetchall_hashref if you're only getting 0/1 rows back why not do a [selectrow_array](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.622/DBI.pm#selectrow_array) or [selectrow_hashref](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.622/DBI.pm#selectall_hashref)?

Comment: I'm getting this from a data access layer that we use in house. Everything gets returned via fetchall_hashref(). I don't call the fetchall_hashref() itself, it's just how the data access functions are implemented internally, so I'm told. I'm a consumer of that returned data that happens to be in that format. I'm looking for a more concise way, if it exists, to access the results of single return value queries.

Comment: Ah - could you update the question to state that using fetchall_hashref is the only way in which you have access to the data please

Answer (score 5):

Why are you using `fetchall_hashref` to fetch a single value? This is better done using [`selectrow_array`](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.622/DBI.pm#selectrow_array):

```
my ($max) = $dbh->selectrow_array($sql);
```

Update: if you can't use another DBI method, a more concise way would be:

```
my $val = [%$results]->[1]{id};
```

Comment: Can someone explain the second expression, please? It is, as @loldop said, something beautiful, but what the heck is `[%$results]`?

Comment: I think I get it: a hash, if converted to a list, is represented by key and value pair, whereof only the value is taken by its index in the list. The value produced by that operation, being a symbolic reference to another hash, can be used to access the hash' values by simple {id} operator (Perl magic)

Comment: So, while my solution might be "perfect" (@sinan-unur), I personally will remember this one with a passion :)

Comment: @fork0: it's a reference to an array containing key/value pairs of `%$results` From [perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html): hashes included as parts of other lists (...) always flatten out into key/value pairs.

Comment: Devilishly clever, @eugeney. Hats off to you. However, it's almost as obscure as the original code. Nonetheless, a fine piece of Perl golf. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Does your data access layer always return a hash with sequential keys?  If so, then what about

```
$results->{1}{id}
```

(Of course, it may not... but your example data used the key `1` for the first record, so it's possible that the data access layer may use deterministic keys.)

Answer (score 0):

```
my @keys = sort { $a <=> $b } keys %$results;
my $first = $keys[0];
$results->{$first}->{id};
```

or if $first = 1;

```
$results->{1}->{id};
```